# Dart accessing functions as objects. How to invoke them?

Tags: function, object, dart

I'm using an array of objects and one of the objects is a function. I tried invoking it the normal way but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried type casting it didn't work either.

```
List<Object> list = ['some other type of data', (String p) { /* do something */}];

list[1]('some string'); // Expression doesn't evaluate to a function
```

I need to somehow invoke the function at index 1 of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do what you want

```
(list[1] as void Function(String))('some string');
```

or just

```
(list[1] as Function)('some string');
```

Comment: You could also use a `typedef` instead of `void Function(...)` to make it reusable.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution. I have tried the typecasting in java way which doesn't seem to work on dart.

Here's what I did,

```
List<Object> list = ['some other type of data', (String p) { /* do something */}];
Function f = list[1];
f('some string'); // This worked!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the list type to dynamic like so:

```
List<dynamic> list = ['some other type of data', (String p){ print('hi-$p');}];

list[1]('dart'); //Output is: hi-dart
```